# jsFiddle how to get json?

Tags: json, echo, openlayers, jsfiddle

Hy,

I'm working on a jsFiddle with a openlayers example in it.
http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/snapping.html

At the moment it's not working because it's not getting a response for the http request to get data. How do I fix that?

The jsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/TcuxA/6/
Go to the line "// create three vector layers" in the script.
There are 3 requests for data. If you type the URLs in your browser you get the JSON, but my firebug gives 3 errors when I run the jsFiddle.

I tried fixing with jsFiddle echo ( http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html ), but that didn't work. I don't know how to change the script to load the data otherwise.

Why can't I get the json by these URLs? What are good sollutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are experiencing is an exception being thrown by the XMLHttpRequest object, because you are using `AJAX` to call elements from different domain. [This is better said, for example, in here:](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/calling-cross-domain-web-services-in-ajax/)

*"The XMLHttpRequest object is prevented from calling web services from outside its own domain. This is sensible given that if you called a script in one place and it, in turn, called a script on another server, it could leave an application open to all sorts of malicious scripts, hacks and exploits."*

So the easiest way to do is to code it locally and call a local copy of the files (poly.json, line.json and point.json) that would reside on your local server. For testing if all displays on a map you could hard-code the files into your code. I am not sure how it could be achieved otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution can be this : [using github responses](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/github_response.html) .  You can store your example in github, along with the predefined XHR requests responses.